Bathroom fan (sometimes) turns on and off when using countdown timer switch
Bath fan Model: Panasonic FV-0511VF1
Timer switch Model: Lutron MA-T51MN-WH
The bath fan is cycling on and off at a very low level (i.e. it doesn't come close to spinning the fan up all the way).
Based on my research, it is because the timer switch doesn't support low power fan.
However, my timer switch model has a neutral and all internet article that describes similar problem with me suggests to use the switch of my model.
The main interesting point in my case is that this problem doesn't happen all the time. It happens like once per week.
Here's another interesting observation: My house has 4 same fans with same timer switch. Once I observe the problem from one timer switch, the rest of the timer switches show the same problem. After waiting for few hours (sometimes tomorrow morning), it comes back to normal and works well.
If I need to buy another timer switch, what do you recommend to buy?
Or is there anything that I need to look into?
Can anyone help?
thanks!

Have you contacted Lutron's tech support yet?

meassure the voltage during those times

Is your area suffering brownouts?
